# Image Indexing Google Search

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-image-search

I have large website for Hindi and [Gujarati Shayari](https://quotesdiary.com).

It have about 80000+ Hindi and Gujarati Shayari pages.
its successfully indexed in Google and I am getting enough organic search traffic.
My Post page contains full size image and text shayari like this.

[image]

You can see example URL for the same here.

```
https://quotesdiary.com/gu/post/romantic-shayari-gujarati-69394
```

Page is index successfully but I have blocked image folder to index using robots.txt file because I was have marked that google was indexing my images with image URL like

```
https://quotesdiary.com/uploads/images/quotes/hi/webp/romantic-status-shayari-11829.webp
```

so image was getting displayed in Google Search in images section like this

[image]

Its fine but some images got indexed with direct images link instead page link so I was not getting user to my website thats reason I was have blocked uploads directory to index using robots.txt file.

Now My confusion is

I want page to index with image so when user click on image, he can come on my website. Today I have received indexing issue from Google search like

```
Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site.

Top Issues

    Blocked by robots.txt

We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.
```

and example URL is given my images url instead of page URL by Google like

```
https://quotesdiary.com/uploads/images/quotes/hi/webp/romantic-status-shayari-11829.webp
https://quotesdiary.com/uploads/images/quotes/gu/webp/yaad-status-shayari-47751.webp
```

and some other similar images URL.

I am new to SEO so I do not know I should block uploads directory or not, it will cause any issue in my page indexing or not, I want allow google to show image from my page, so user can find image and click on it and can come on my site.

Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a WordPress site?  Have you tweaked [this setting](https://yoast.com/help/redirect-image-attachment-urls/) to redirect the attachment page to the image itself?  WordPress by default does this dumb thing were it creates an HTML page for every image that does nothing but show the image in the page.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend caring too much about image search. Very few users click through from image search and end up engaging with your site, even if image search is linking to your pages correctly. Engagement rates from image search are a tiny fraction (less than 10%) of engagement rates from web search.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for Your comment. 1) its not wordpress, I have built it using Bootstrap and PHP. 2) Since its Quotes (Poetry) related website and main attraction of the site is Quotes with image, so I am getting lot of clicks through images, thats the reason I am worried for images. I hope You will understand my situation. Thanks!